# Como carregar as informações dentro do modal (bootstrap 3.3.6)?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, modal

Estou querendo que no modal, após clicar na opção visualizar, ele carregue as informações. Porém, ele carrega apenas o ID 1 da tabela, independente de qual item da tabela eu deseje visualizar. Ele traz sempre a mesma informação. Abaixo está o código de como eu estou fazendo.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-striped" data-toggle="table"
           data-search="true"
           data-show-refresh="true"
           data-show-columns="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="th-small" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
                <th data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Nome</th>
                <th class="th-small">Ações</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ($idade as $key => $v) {
                ?>
                <tr>

                    <td><?= $v->id ?></td>
                    <td><?= $v->titulo ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <form data-toggle="validator" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="submit" data-toggle="dropdown">... <span class="caret"></span></button>
                            <ul class="table-modal dropdown-menu">
                                <li class=""><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-select">Visualizar</a></li>
                                <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editarIdade">Editar</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- Modal VISUALIZAR -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-select" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="cadastroIdadelLabel">Visualizar - Idade</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-inline" role="form" data-toggle="validator" action="Idade/page/visualizar">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div>
                                    <label>Idade:</label>
                                    <?= $v->titulo ?>

                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label>Código:</label>
                                    <?= $v->id ?>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Voltar</button>

                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passei pelo mesmo problema há alguns meses. Para solucionar o caso, fiz da seguinte maneira.

- Fiz uma nova página .php somente para o conteúdo do modal.

  ```
  <?php include('config.php'); // Arquivo de acesso ao banco de dados

  if(isset($_GET['id_registro'])) // Recebe o ID do registro que deseja carregar
  {
      ?>
          <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Legal</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              Conteúdo do modal. Coloque aqui todo o código que quer que apareça dentro do modal.
              Faça a pesquisa no banco de dados em php, etc...
          </div>
      <?php
  } php?>
  ```
- Coloquei o "molde" do modal na página em que o modal será usado.

  ```
  <div id="idDivModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Agora o link que, ao ser clicado, vai abrir o modal com as informações do banco de dados (deve ficar na página em que o modal será usado).

  ```
  <a href='#idDivModal' role='button' data-toggle='modal' data-load-remote='paginamodal.php?id_registro=".$id_registro."' data-remote-target='#idDivModal .modal-content' title='Título' aria-hidden='true' />
  ```
- Por fim, o código JavaScript que vai fazer isso funcionar (deve ficar na página em que o modal será usado).

  ```
  <script>
   $('[data-load-remote]').on('click',function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this);
      var remote = $this.data('load-remote');
      if(remote) {
          $($this.data('remote-target')).load(remote);
      }
   });
  </script>
  ```

Pronto. É isso. Agora não se esqueça de incluir o Bootstrap e o jQuery na sua página.